React select shows extra element that is not in the array assigned to value
I am learning how to use components in React.  I have a parent called Quote.jsx that has a child called QuoteData.jsx.  I send the value of selectedCharacters from the parent to the child.  On the child I am using a react-select control.  The react-select control's value is set to selectedCharacters.
I know selectedCharacters only has 2 elements in it because I can see that on the screen via the temporary output message I put in there that checks the length of selectedCharacters and shows the values in those 2 elements.  But the react-select element shows an extra blank element and I cannot figure out why.
Since a picture's worth a thousand, this is what I mean

And it's not only a single element.  I mean it is when I first load the page but as I use the navigation buttons, extra blank items are showing in the react-select.
My jsx files look like this:
Quote.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
//import Select from 'react-select';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import './App.css';
import Processing from './Processing';
import QuoteData from './QuoteData';

function Quote() {
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState({ Text: '', Id: 0, Formatted: '', IsActive: true,  Characters: [] }); 
  const [allCharacters, setAllCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCharacters, setSelectedCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [allQuoteIds, setAllQuoteIds] = useState([]);
  const [currentQuoteIdIndex, setCurrentQuoteIdIndex] = useState(0);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('optAll');
  const [statusCount, setStatusCount] = useState({formatted_count: 0, non_formatted_count: 0, total_count: 0});
  const [loadingIndicator, setLoadingIndicator] = useState(true)
  

  // ---------------------- HOOKS ---------------------- 
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      getAllQuoteIds();
      getCharacterData();
      getStatusCount();
    } catch (error) {
      showToast('error', 'Error gathering initial data.  Error reported is ' + error.message)
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      getQuoteData();
      setSelectedCharacters(quote.Characters)
    } catch (error) {
      showToast('error', 'Problem getting/setting quote data' + error.message)
    }
  }, [allQuoteIds, currentQuoteIdIndex]);


  // ---------------------- HELPERS ---------------------- 
  const showToast = (type, message) => {
    const toastOptions = {
      position: "top-center",
      autoClose: 500,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress:undefined,
    }

    if (type === "warning") {
      toast.warning(message, {toastOptions});
    } else if (type === "success") {
      toast.success(message, {toastOptions});
    } else if (type === "error") {
      toast.error(message, {toastOptions})
    } else if (type === "info") {
      toast.info(message, {toastOptions})
    } else {
      toast.error('Unknown issue occurred when trying to display status', {toastOptions})
    }
  }

  const getCharacterData = async () => {
    try {
      loadCharacters(false);
    } catch (error) {
      showToast('error', 'Problem getting/loading character data.  Problem reported: ' + error.message);
    }
  };


  // ----------------------  GET CALLS ---------------------- 
  const getQuoteData = async () => {
    if(allQuoteIds[currentQuoteIdIndex] === undefined) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      try {
        let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/AdminAPI/getOneQuote/' + allQuoteIds[currentQuoteIdIndex]
        const response = await axios.get(
          url,
          {
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }
        );
        if (response.status === 200) { 
          setLoadingIndicator(false);
          setQuote(response.data.quotes[0]);
          setSelectedCharacters(response.data.quotes[0].Characters.map((character) => ({
            value: character.Id,
            label: character.ShortName,
          })));
        } else {
          showToast('error', 'Problem getting quote data');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        showToast('error', 'Problem getting quote data.  Problem reported: ' + error.message);
      }
    }
  };

 
  const getAllQuoteIds = async (whatToShow = 'optAll') => {
    try {
      let urlBase = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/AdminAPI/getAllQuoteIds';
      let url = '';
      
      if (whatToShow === "optFormatted") {
        url = urlBase + '?formatted=true';
      }
      else if (whatToShow === "optNonFormatted") {
        url = urlBase + '?formatted=false';
      } 
      else {
        url = urlBase;
      }
  
      const response = await axios.get(
        url, 
        {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
      setAllQuoteIds(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      showToast('error', 'Problem getting quoteID data.  Problem reported: ' + error.message);
    }
  }

  const getStatusCount = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/AdminAPI/GetQuoteFormattingStatusCount', 
        {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
      setStatusCount(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      showToast('error', 'Problem getting status count data.  Problem reported: ' + error.message);
    }
  }

  // ----------------------  POST CALLS ----------------------  

  const saveQuote = async () => {
    try {
      const quoteData = {
        Id: quote.Id, 
        Text: quote.Text,
        Characters: selectedCharacters.map((character) => character.value), 
        Formatted: true, 
        IsActive: quote.IsActive
      };
  
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/AdminAPI/saveQuote', quoteData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
    
        // Handle successful response
        if (response.status === 200) {
          showToast("success", "Quote saved successfully!")
          getStatusCount();
          handleNavigationChange({ target: {value: "next"}});
        } else {
          showToast("error", "Error saving quote")
  //        toast.error('Error saving quote');
          //TODO: Put in logging
        }
      } catch (error) {
        showToast("error", "Error saving quote")
  //      toast.error('Error saving quote');
        //TODO: Put in logging
        }
      } catch (error) {
        showToast('error', 'Problem saving quote data.  Problem reported: ' + error.message);
      }
  };


  // ----------------------  EVENT HANDLING ----------------------  
  const handleNavigationChange = (event) => {

    if (event.target.value === "start") {
      setCurrentQuoteIdIndex(0); 
    } else if (event.target.value === "prev"){
      if (currentQuoteIdIndex === 0){
        showToast("warning", "Cannot move backward any further")
      } else {
        setCurrentQuoteIdIndex(currentQuoteIdIndex-1);
      }
    } else if (event.target.value === "next"){
      if (currentQuoteIdIndex >= allQuoteIds.length-1) {
            showToast("warning", "Cannot move forward any further")
        } else {
            setCurrentQuoteIdIndex(currentQuoteIdIndex+1);
        }
    } else {
      setCurrentQuoteIdIndex(allQuoteIds.length-1)
    }
  }

  const handleQuoteChange = (event) => {
    setQuote({ ...quote, Text: event.target.value }); 
  };

  const handleCharChange = (selected) => {
    setSelectedCharacters(selected);
    setQuote({...quote, Characters: selected });
  };

  const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    setLoadingIndicator(true);
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
    getAllQuoteIds(event.target.value);
  };
  
  const handleIsActiveChange = (event) => {
    setQuote({ ...quote, IsActive: event.target.checked }); 
  }
 
  const handleClickReloadCharacters = (event) => {
    loadCharacters(true);
  };

  const loadCharacters = async (showSuccessMessage) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5000/AdminAPI/getAllCharacters',
        {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );
  
      const formattedCharacters = response.data.characters.map((character) => ({
          value: character.Id,
          label: character.ShortName,
        }));
      setAllCharacters(formattedCharacters);
      if (showSuccessMessage) {
        showToast('info', 'Characters loaded')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      showToast('error', 'Problem getting/loading character data.  Problem reported: ' + error.message);
    }
  }      


  // ----------------------  PAGE ----------------------  
  return (
    <div>
      <ToastContainer/>
      <br/>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleOptionChange}>
              <option value="optAll">Show All Quotes</option>
              <option value="optFormatted">Only Show Formatted Quotes</option>
              <option value="optNonFormatted">Only Show Non-Formatted Quotes</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{height: "10%"}}>&nbsp;</div>
            {
              loadingIndicator === false ? (
              <QuoteData 
                quote={quote} 
                onCharChange={handleCharChange} 
                onIsActiveChange={handleIsActiveChange}
                onQuoteChange={handleQuoteChange}
                allCharacters={allCharacters}
                selectedCharacters={selectedCharacters}
                >
              </QuoteData>
            ) : (
              <div className="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                style={{padding: "20px", height: "50vh", width: "50vw"}}>
                <Processing></Processing>
              </div>
            )}

        <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={saveQuote}>Save Quote</button> 
        <br/><br/>
        <button className='btn btn-primary' value="start" onClick={handleNavigationChange}>Start</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button className='btn btn-primary' value="prev" onClick={handleNavigationChange}>Prev</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button className='btn btn-primary' value="next" onClick={handleNavigationChange}>Next</button> 
        &nbsp;
        <button className='btn btn-primary' value="end" onClick={handleNavigationChange}>End</button>
        <br/><br/>
        <button className='btn btn-primary' value="reloadCharacters" onClick={handleClickReloadCharacters}>Reload Characters</button>
        <br/><br/>
        <div className="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          Formatted: {statusCount.formatted_count} of {statusCount.total_count} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div className="progress" style={{height: "40px", width: "50%"}} >
          <div className="progress-bar bg-success" style={{width: ((statusCount.formatted_count/statusCount.total_count)*100).toString() + "%"}} >
            { Math.fround((statusCount.formatted_count/statusCount.total_count)*100).toFixed(2)}%
          </div>
          <div className="progress-bar bg-danger" style={{width: ((statusCount.non_formatted_count/statusCount.total_count)*100).toString() + "%"}} >
            { Math.fround((statusCount.non_formatted_count/statusCount.total_count)*100).toFixed(2)}%
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Quote;

QuoteData.jsx
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 
import './App.css';
import Select from 'react-select';

function QuoteData ({quote, allCharacters, selectedCharacters, onIsActiveChange, onQuoteChange, onCharChange}) {

      const handleCharChange = (selected) => {
        const formattedSelected = selected || [];
        onCharChange(formattedSelected);
      };


      return (
        <div>
        <div className='container'> 
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col text-start'>
            {quote.Book.Title}
            </div>
            <div className="col text-end">
            Quote ID: {quote.Id}
            <text value={quote.Id} type="hidden"></text>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-lg'>
            <textarea className="form-control border border-primary" 
                style={{ fontSize: '18px'}}
                value={quote.Text} rows="17" 
                onChange={onQuoteChange}
                disabled={!quote.IsActive}
            />

            {/* For testing only */}
            SelectedCharacters length is {selectedCharacters.length}
            <br></br>
            {selectedCharacters && selectedCharacters.length > 0 ? (
            <div>
                <ul>
                {selectedCharacters.map((character) => (
                    <li key={character.value}>{character.label}</li> // Display ShortName in a list item
                ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
            ) : (
            <div>No characters selected</div>
            )}
            {/* end for testing */}
            <div>
            <Select
                isMulti
                options = {
                    allCharacters
                }
                value={selectedCharacters}
                onChange={handleCharChange}
            >
            </Select>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkIsActive" checked={quote.IsActive} onChange={onIsActiveChange} />
            <label htmlFor="chkIsActive"> Is Active</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default QuoteData

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me understand where this (these after navigation) extra element(s) are coming from.  Thanks!

Can you create a [mre]?

@NickParsons, thank you.  I was working up one when I thought of a few more things I should try.  They're described in my answer below.  But I just wanted to thank you for answering.  :)

Nice, glad you worked it out in the end :)

I managed to figure this out.  Just dropping this here in case it helps some other newbie.
I put a breakpoint on the  and watched what was happening in the control.  I noticed it was being hit a few times.  For the first couple of times the control's selected values stayed what they should be.  But at some point there were two blank "cards" in there.  Then the proper characters would reappear but one blank "card" remained.  As I stepped through the navigation elements (forwards or backwards didn't matter) most of the time more cards were being added.  Not every time, mind you, but a majority.
That made me think I was getting caught up in the control being modified after it was rendered.  Or something like that.  Anyway,I realized I didn't need the "const formattedSelected...." line in here.
const handleCharChange = (selected) => {
    const formattedSelected = selected || [];
    onCharChange(formattedSelected); };

  
  

And then I woke up with the realization that since handleCharChage was now doing nothing but calling onCharChange from the parent, there was no reason to have it.  So I commented it out and moved the call to onCharChage to the control, like so:
<Select
    name="multiselect"
    isMulti = "true"
    options = {allCharacters}
    value={selectedCharacters}
    onChange={onCharChange}
>

That did the trick and now only selectedCharacters members are all that show in the Select control - no additional !%#$#%#$@%^$% empty "cards".  :D
Anyway, just adding this answer in case it helps some other newbie.
